# How to take a hash from Perl array?

Tags: perl

This is the code:

```
my @items = (); # this is the array
my %x = {}; # the hash I'm going to put into the array
$x{'aa'} = 'bb'; # fill it up with one key-value pair
push(@items, $x); # add it to the array
my %i = @items[0]; # taking it back
print $i{'aa'}; # taking the value by the key
```

I expect it to print `bb`, but it doesn't print anything. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> What am I doing wrong?

Well, this doesn't do what you think:

```
my %x = {};
```

You can easily check:

```
use Data::Dumper;
print Dumper \%x;
```

The output:

```
Reference found where even-sized list expected at ./1.pl line 5.
$VAR1 = {
          'HASH(0x556a69fe8220)' => undef
        };
```

The first line comes from `use warnings;`. If you don't use it, start now.

Why is the contents of the hash so strange? The curly braces create a hash reference. As keys must be strings, the reference is stringified to the `HASH(0xADDR)`. You don't want a reference, you want a list of keys and values.

```
my %x = ();
```

In fact, each hash and array starts up empty, so you don't have to use anything:

```
my @items;
my %x;
```

Or, you can populate it right ahead instead of doing it separately on the next line:

```
my %x = (aa => 'bb');
```

Similarly, this doesn't work:

```
push @items, $x;
```

It pushes value of the scalar variable `$x` into `@items`, but there's no such variable. It seems you aren't using `use strict;`. Start now, it will save you from similar errors.

You want to push the hash to the array, but array values are scalars - so you need to take a reference of the hash instead.

```
push @items, \%x;
```

No, you want to retrieve the hash from the array. Again, this doesn't work:

```
my %i = @items[0];
```

You are extracting a single value. Therefore, you shouldn't use `@`. Moreover, we now have a reference in the array, to populate a hash, we need to dereference it first:

```
my %i = %{ $items[0] };
```

And voilà, it works!

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my @items;               # this is the array
my %x;                   # the hash I'm going to put into the array
$x{aa} = 'bb';           # fill it up with one key-value pair
push @items, \%x;        # add it to the array
my %i = %{ $items[0] };  # taking it back
print $i{aa};            # taking the value by the key
```